# Forward and Reverse DNS zones are allocated different NameServers

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

Will Reverse DNS lookup resolve/work if Forward and Reverse DNS zones are allocated different NameServers?

Note: Observed this as default behavior of Google Cloud DNS service.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Forward and reverse zones are entirely separate zones, and there is no technical connection between them. The only connection is that the data in one has a well-known relation to the data in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Calle for taking time to look into my query. But here below I finally got answer to my question --> http://www.dnsstuff.com/reverse-dns-faq

Thought it would be worth sharing here:

Very Common Myth:

```
* Myth: If you have a reverse DNS entry listed in your DNS server, you have reverse DNS properly set up.
  Fact: This is often not the case. You need TWO things in order to have your DNS set up properly:
      o 1. Your DNS servers (or your ISP's) MUST have the reverse DNS entries set up ("25.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. PTR host.example.com").
      o 2. AND your ISP or bandwidth provider MUST set up the reverse DNS on their end, so that DNS resolvers around the world will know that your DNS servers are the ones to go to when looking up the reverse DNS for your IP addresses.
```